So im using an AWS S3 bucket server for Storing files, now i have to create an api for deleting that file. Help me out?
So this is the my Controller layer where i have created a method for deleteFiles from AWS and DataBase at the same time.
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/images")
public class ImageController {  
@DeleteMapping(path = "/delete/file/{bucketName}/{imageUrl}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteFile(@PathVariable String bucketName, @PathVariable String imageUrl) {
        boolean isDeleted = imageService.deleteFile(bucketName, imageUrl);
        if (isDeleted) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("File deleted successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("File deletion failed", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}

**This is my Service layer - **
@Service
public class ImageService { 
@Transactional
    public boolean deleteFile(String bucketName, String imageUrl) {
        try {
          String fileName = imageUrl.substring(imageUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

            // Delete the file from S3 bucket
            amazonS3.deleteObject(new DeleteObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName));
            // Delete the file reference from the database
            imagesRepository.deleteByImageUrl(imageUrl);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

**
I have created a Repository where i have build a query for deleting record form my data base -**
public interface ImagesRepository extends JpaRepository<Images, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("DELETE FROM Images i WHERE i.imageUrl LIKE %:imageUrl%")
    void deleteByImageUrl(@Param("imageUrl") String imageUrl);
}

Im trying to delete a record with this url -
URL - http://localhost:8080/api/v1/images/delete/file/airbnb-images/https://airbnb-images.s3.amazonaws.com/Manali2.jpg
Getting an Error in postman -
{
    "timestamp": "2024-05-29T09:18:48.782+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/api/v1/images/delete/file/airbnb-images/https://airbnb-images.s3.amazonaws.com/Manali2.jpg"
}

what should i have to do for a solution?

Look in your server logs where it should show why it returned HTTP 400.

Not ideal to include a URL (https://airbnb-images.s3.amazonaws.com/Manali2.jpg) unencoded within another URL (https://server/api/v1/images/delete/file/...).

You might consider modifying your API to be something like /api/v1/images/delete/file?bucket=x&key=y so in your testcase that would include ?bucket=airbnb-images&key=Manali2.jpg. However, this is really not an ideal API because you have introduced a confused deputy security problem. Specifically, the client can indicate any bucket name and any object key and if your controller happens to have permission for the indicated bucket, which is not airbnb-images, then it will delete the indicated object.

Use the AWS SDK Java version that is the best practice. You are currently using Version 1, which is on the path to deprecation. This is V1 code as V2 does not use the new operator.  amazonS3.deleteObject(new DeleteObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName));

Here the solution
We cannot send a URL type value into a @PathVariable; it should come from @RequestParam where you can send a request as a key-value pair.
